# Set a background color for several adjacent cells and "page"

Tags: cells, stylesheet, background

I'm using a book style sheet but this question applies to the standard notebook interface as well.

I'm writing a sequence of cells in different styles (text, equation, figure, figure caption, ...) in a special section (e.g., "Example") and would like to color the background of all content in the Example.  I group the cells, click-select the associated grouping bar and select ***Format>Background color*** to be pink (for example).  This changes the background in each cell to be pink. Great!

Almost...

This procedure colors the background of the *cells*, but not of the "page" behind.  This looks a bit choppy and ununified, as here:

[image: two cells with same background color]

Merging cells forces them to be the same style, which of course is not appropriate (as I have text, equations, ...).

I'm seeking a way to color the *background* page as well, but of course *just between the beginning and end of the chosen cells*.  I'm not interested in the global option of setting the background color of the *entire* document.

There are several questions here about setting the backgrounds of multiple cells with a single command, but none that I could find that colors the "page" as well.

Comment: There's an option in preferences under `Advanced>Open Option Inspector>Notebook Options>Display Options>Background` that changes the whole page background. But it sounds like you just want it behind the certain cells. Maybe there's an option to reduce the padding at the top and bottom of these special cells to 0, so adjacent cells appear as one long cell?

Comment: @N.J.Evans:  Indeed... as I pointed out I want to highly *just* the "Example" (or other) section.  I'll edit my post to clarify.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork the trick is to set `CellMargins -> {{r, l}, {0, 0}` and `CellFrameMargins->{{0, 0}, {bottom, top}}` which visually merges the two but retains the padding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I can show the pic:

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Text", CellMargins}]

{{66, 10}, {7, 8}}

CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Text", CellFrameMargins}]

8

Cell[
  CellGroupData[
   {
    Cell[
     "top",
     "Text",
     FontColor -> White,
     Background -> Pink,
     CellMargins -> {{66, 10}, {0, 0}},
     CellFrameMargins -> {{8, 8}, {7, 8}}
     ],
    Cell[
     "bottom",
     "Text",
     FontColor -> White,
     Background -> Pink,
     CellMargins -> {{66, 10}, {0, 0}},
     CellFrameMargins -> {{8, 8}, {7, 8}}
     ]
    },
   Open
   ]
  ] // CellPrint
```

[image]

With different colors

```
Cell[
  CellGroupData[
   {
    Cell[
     "top",
     "Text",
     FontColor -> White,
     Background -> Pink,
     CellMargins -> {{66, 10}, {0, 0}},
     CellFrameMargins -> {{8, 8}, {7, 8}}
     ],
    Cell[
     "bottom",
     "Text",
     FontColor -> Black,
     Background -> LightBlue,
     CellMargins -> {{66, 10}, {0, 0}},
     CellFrameMargins -> {{8, 8}, {7, 8}}
     ]
    },
   Open
   ]
  ] // CellPrint
```

[image]

This obviously admits a simple stylesheet solution too

Per the comment, Mathematica doesn't resize content in the `CellFrameLabels` (you can look up on the site the many, many attempts to make that content resize properly). This is a problem with numbered equations. There are three straightforward solutions.
The first is less flexible but works with documents where the cell heights can be parametrized

```
Cell[CellGroupData[{
    Cell["blah", "DisplayFormulaNumbered", FontColor -> White, 
     Background -> Pink,
     CellMargins -> {{66, 3}, {0, 0}},
     CellFrameMargins -> {{8, 8}, {4, 4}},
     CellFrameLabelMargins -> 0,
     CellFrameLabels -> {
       {None,
        Cell[
         TextData[{"(", CounterBox["DisplayFormulaNumbered"], ")"
           }], "DisplayFormulaEquationNumber",
         CellMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}},
         CellFrameMargins -> {{5, 5}, {4, 4}},
         TextAlignment -> {Center, Center},
         CellSize -> {Automatic, 26}
         ]
        },
       {None, None}
       }
     ],
    Cell["top", "FigureCaption", FontColor -> Black, Background -> LightBlue,
     CellMargins -> {{66, 3}, {0, 0}},
     CellFrameMargins -> {{8, 8}, {4, 4}}
     ]
    }, Open]
  ] // CellPrint
```

[image]

You'll notice it spans fine, but this is fragile because I hard-coded the height and it also floats oddly to the top-right corner and this is basically unfixable.

The second option is to remove the background on the labels and make sure the label widths are identical

```
Cell[CellGroupData[{
    Cell["blah", "DisplayFormulaNumbered", FontColor -> White, 
     Background -> Pink,
     CellMargins -> {{66, 3}, {0, 0}},
     CellFrameMargins -> {{8, 8}, {4, 4}},
     CellFrameLabels -> {
       {None,
        Cell[
         TextData[{"(", CounterBox["DisplayFormulaNumbered"], ")"}], 
         "DisplayFormulaEquationNumber",
         FontColor -> Pink,
         Background -> None,
         CellSize -> {25, Automatic},
         CellMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
         ]
        },
       {None, None}
       }
     ],
    Cell["top", "FigureCaption", FontColor -> Black, Background -> LightBlue,
     CellMargins -> {{66, 3}, {0, 0}},
     CellFrameMargins -> {{8, 8}, {4, 4}},
     CellFrameLabels -> {
       {None,
        Cell[
         "",
         "DisplayFormulaEquationNumber",
         CellSize -> {25, Automatic},
         Background -> None,
         CellMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
         ]
        },
       {None, None}
       }
     ]
    }, Open]
  ] // CellPrint
```

[image]

This is a much more robust solution. It is worth noting that the width is hard coded.

A final possibility, again, where the label width is hard coded, is to use a negative value for `CellFrameLabelMargins`. To do this, again, both the upper and lower cells need a label.

```
Cell[CellGroupData[{
    Cell["blah", "DisplayFormulaNumbered", FontColor -> White, 
     Background -> Pink,
     CellMargins -> {{66, 3}, {0, 0}},
     CellFrameMargins -> {{8, 8}, {4, 4}},
     CellFrameLabelMargins -> -20
     ],
    Cell["top", "FigureCaption", FontColor -> Black, Background -> LightBlue,
     CellMargins -> {{66, 3}, {0, 0}},
     CellFrameMargins -> {{8, 8}, {4, 4}},
     CellFrameLabelMargins -> -20,
     CellFrameLabels -> {
       {None,
        Cell[
         "",
         "DisplayFormulaEquationNumber",
         Background -> None,
         CellMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
         ]
        },
       {None, None}
       }
     ]
    }, Open]
  ] // CellPrint
```

[image]

If you're interested in using these cells, make sure the starting content will allow you to type what you want (i.e. `""` for text, `BoxData[""]` for code, and `BoxData@FormBox["", TraditionalForm]` for equations). Here's an example of this with equations

```
Cell[
  CellGroupData[{
    Cell[
     BoxData@FormBox["", TraditionalForm],
     "DisplayFormulaNumbered",
     TextAlignment -> Center, FontColor -> White, Background -> Pink, 
     CellMargins -> {{66, 3}, {0, 0}}, CellFrameMargins -> {{8, 8}, {4, 4}}, 
     CellFrameLabelMargins -> -20], 
    Cell["top", "FigureCaption", FontColor -> Black, Background -> LightBlue, 
     CellMargins -> {{66, 3}, {0, 0}}, CellFrameMargins -> {{8, 8}, {4, 4}}, 
     CellFrameLabelMargins -> -20, 
     CellFrameLabels -> {{None, 
        Cell["", "DisplayFormulaEquationNumber", Background -> None, 
         CellMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}]}, {None, None}}]},
   Open]
  ] // CellPrint
```

then I can type math in the top cell

[image]

Comment: This is a great step in the right direction, thanks (+1).  But I couldn't modify your code to get other cell types, such as **EquationNumbered** (complete with automatic numbering and such), **FigureCaption**, and so on.  Could you repost with a mixture of cell types?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork it's harder to be general for this case, but option three in what I just posted mostly gets you there

Comment: @bwm2a1:  This is so close... but I still cannot get a true equation (e.g., x^2 + y^2) in the DisplayFormulaNumbered cell, where the exponents are properly set, fractions, integral signs, ...

Comment: @DavidG.Stork use `BoxData[""]` instead of `"blah"`. That ought to fix it.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork or to really get things right: `BoxData@FormBox["", TraditionalForm]`

Comment: Nope... both give me the "x^2" not the $x^2$ I seek.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork How are you trying to input this? Just as plain text in the cell? Or are you typing in the cell after it's made? The first cannot work unless you use `SubscriptBox`/`SuperscriptBox` and friends. Using `BoxData@FormBox["", TraditionalForm]` and typing in the generated cell gives me standard `DisplayFormulaNumbered` typesetting

Comment: Got it!  Thanks so very much! ($\checkmark$)